# Statement is incomplete mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure from mysql workbench but I am getting an error :

```
create procedure users_getInfoByNameAndHash
(
    IN name varchar(255), 
    IN hash varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
    Select * from users 
    where userName = name 
    and password = hash;
END;
```

I have a red squiggly line under hash and if I hover my mouse over it it says:

> Statement is incomplete, expecting ";"

If I execute the query I get:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '' at line 9

Comment: Did you use DELIMITER? Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: hash is a keyword not a reserved word so I would not expect issues with it (for now) what ide are you using?